# Tweet button not displayed properly in IE7 but working fine in mozilla, chrome and IE 8

Tags: javascript, twitter

I added tweet button code in my website which is generated from twitter resources(default javascript version). This code works fine and shows tweet button properly in mozilla, chrome and IE 8 but same pages not displayed properly in IE 7. In IE 7 tweet button's width is showed very high that it shows horizontal scroll bar. Why this is happening?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This could be a css error of the context. Can you post a link or show some code?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The code that I used is as follows        <a href="pageurl" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @sitename</a>
       <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got solution for it. I manually override css in my css file as .twitter-follow-button {width: 150px !important;} to display it proper.

Comment: I'm having the SAME exact issue in IE7. I've seen other posting around the interweb about that, not sure if they plan to fix this or not. They must be dynamically setting the iframe width...

Comment: Either that or they no longer support IE7.

Answer (score 0):

This was  a known issue in IE7 and this bug has been fixed as per twitter.

https://dev.twitter.com/issues/200