# Twitter "Tweet" Button IE7 Bug (cut off text)

Tags: twitter, twitter-button

I'm trying to use the Twitter "Tweet" button on a site. It works great in all browsers, but in IE 7, it doesn't show the full width. There's no additional CSS in place, other than a little `padding-left` on the LinkedIn button for spacing.

Twitter have said that they fixed this issue a few months ago [here](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/200), but I'm using the latest code from their developers site with no luck.

I've also tried the solution from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084106/tweet-button-not-displayed-properly-in-ie7-but-working-fine-in-mozilla-chrome-a) suggesting to use `.twitter-follow-button {width: 150px !important;}`, but this also didn't solve the issue. The image below shows how it looks in IE7, with the text incorrectly cut short.

[image: The cut-off Twitter button in IE7]

Any advice or suggestions of where to go next would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us a working demo? The problem may be due to some other bug in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a surrounding  for the Twitter button that was being placed in-line, hence there wasn't a sign of it in the CSS. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the Twitter Share button instead of the Twitter Follow button. Therefore the used class as suggested by the quoted stackoverflow thread will not work. You should be using:

```
.twitter-share-button {width: 150px !important;}
```